# Parsing html, pyparser or beautifulsoup

Tags: python

Coast (NS / WS) = EUR35.99 / US$46.09

Money Object = EUR42.00 / US$53.79

```
<div id="t142_1" class="text" >Data Center</div>
<div id="t143_1" class="text" >Coast (NS / WS)</div>
<div id="t144_1" class="text" >EUR35.99 / US$46.09</div>
<div id="t145_1" class="text" >Money Object</div>
<div id="t146_1" class="text" >EUR42.00 / US$53.79</div>
<div id="t147_1" class="text" >Date</div>
<div id="t148_1" class="text" >7-Nov-2013 / 7-Nov-2013</div>
<div id="t149_1" class="text" >Opinions</div>
```

How to get from this code value of "Money Object" and "Coast (NS / WS)" using pyparser or beautifulsoup?

I need variables (for example):

```
coast = 'EUR35.99 / US$46.09'

money_obj = 'EUR42.00 / US$53.79'
```

EDIT:

```
a = soup.find_all(text='Money Object')
for i in a:
    print i.find_next('div').text
```

but return:

```
Change

EUR42.00 / US$53.79
```

I need only one value (EUR42.00 / US$53.79)

Answer (score 1):

Where `text` is your example HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(text)
print soup.find(text='Money Object').find_next('div').text
# EUR42.00 / US$53.79
```

Which reads as - find something with `Money Object` as its text content, then take the next `div`s text...

Comment: What if I have several times used the word "Money Object"? I have a bad value in the "next line"

Comment: @user1966421 Then you use `find_all` and loop over results... Not sure why you're getting that message though - it implies you don't have "Money Object" as per your data sample

Comment: @user1966421 to get the first value - just use: `i.find_next('div').text.split('/')[0].strip()`

Comment: Sorry Jon Clements: My code return: Change and EUR42.00 / US$53.79, I need only "EUR42.00 / US$53.79"

Comment: @user1966421 Where does "Change" even appear in your sample data!? Just process the resultant string accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Using `pyparsing` :

```
from pyparsing import *

data = """\
<div id="t142_1" class="text" >Data Center</div>
<div id="t143_1" class="text" >Coast (NS / WS)</div>
<div id="t144_1" class="text" >EUR35.99 / US$46.09</div>
<div id="t145_1" class="text" >Money Object</div>
<div id="t146_1" class="text" >EUR42.00 / US$53.79</div>
<div id="t147_1" class="text" >Date</div>
<div id="t148_1" class="text" >7-Nov-2013 / 7-Nov-2013</div>
<div id="t149_1" class="text" >Opinions</div>
"""

divS,divE = makeHTMLTags("div")

div = divS + SkipTo(divE).setResultsName("body") + divE
divS.setParseAction( withAttribute(id="t144_1") )

for tokens,start,end in div.scanString(data):
    print "cost = " + tokens.body

divS.setParseAction( withAttribute(id="t146_1") )
for tokens,start,end in div.scanString(data):
    print "money_obj = " + tokens.body
```

Output:

```
>>> 
cost = EUR35.99 / US$46.09
money_obj = EUR42.00 / US$53.79
```

Comment: Change those print statements to print function calls and this code still works!